# How to check if profile has a default avatar

Tags: wordpress, avatar, gravatar

[image]

I want to hide the profile if there is a default gravatar. I have tried so  many codes but they didnot give me fruitful result. Because some images are coming from the media folder and some are from 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/'.  Can anyone please let me know how to detect this thing?

Answer (score 1):

```
The get_avatar() returns An img element for the user's avatar or false on failure. The function does not output anything; you have to echo the return value.

Please try below code to check if the profile has a default avatar.

if(!get_the_author_meta('ID')){
        // no img code here     
        echo 'no img code';
    }else{
        $gavar_url = get_avatar_url( $user_email);
        if(strpos($gavar_url,'gravatar.com')!==false){
            //no image code here 
        }else{
            echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID') , 80);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Gufran Hasan for your response. I've tried your above code but page stops working. Currently I'm using the below code to display the avatar.
'get_avatar($post->post_author);'. Can you please check your code again or any another solution to detect that?

Comment: In earlier coed, I have put echo in if condition so that your code was stopped working.

Comment: Okay, Can you share error or issue, now you are getting?

Comment: I have checked the code at my side. It's working fine.

Comment: Are you passing user Id in get_the_author_meta($user_id) function?

Comment: well I'm passing '$post->ID' in  get_the_author_meta

Comment: Okay, Just updated answer. Please try it again, don't know it's not working at your side.

Comment: no again nothing display. I think get_the_author_meta() function is not working at my end.

Comment: Hey @InderpreetSinghSaini, I have tested below code on localhost, It's working fine.
if(!get_the_author_meta('ID')){
   // no img code here  
   echo 'no img code';
  }else{
  echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta(1 ) , 80);
  }

Comment: it's working now but again all the images are coming from the else part. It's not detecting that. Might be some of the profile avatars are coming from 'secure.gravator.com' that's why it's not detecting.

Comment: Is there any another way to detect that?

Comment: Hey @InderpreetSinghSaini, you can do one thing in else case, get avatar url and check 'gravatar.com' is in url. See updated answer, I hope it will work for you as you are looking.

Comment: Hi @Gufran Hasan, thanks for your efforts. I've tried to get the value but again nothing display.

Comment: @InderpreetSinghSaini, Okay now which type issue is comming.